# Solution to probability problems

Tags: probability

could you please help me?

I know the correct solutions which are different from mine, and I absolutely agree that they are correct. However, I cannot find out what's wrong with **my** solutions that typed below.

1)

> Five balls are randomly chosen, without replacement, from an urn that
>   contains 5 red, 6 white, and 7 blue balls. Find the probability that
>   at least one ball of each color is chosen.

Sample space consists of $\binom{18}5$ outcomes. To meet the requirement I need to choose red ball by $\binom51$ ways, white - $\binom61$ and blue - $\binom71$. At the moment we have 3 out of 5 balls. The final balls could be drawn by $\binom{18-3}2$. Thus, the answer is

$$\binom51 \binom61 \binom71 \binom{15}2 / \binom{18}5$$

The most terrible thing about the above solution is that the probability exceeds 1.

2)

> Balls are randomly removed from an urn initially containing 20 red and
>   10 blue balls. What is the probability that all of the red balls are
>   removed before all of the blue ones have been removed?

Imagine 30-element vector that could be filled with either letter "r" or "b". Hence, sample space consists of $2^{30}$ outcomes.

Obviously, the last element in this vector must be "b". That leaves 29 positions to be occupied, i.e. $2^{29}$ outcomes.

The probability is $2^{29}/2^{30} = \frac12$

---

Could you help me to find flaw(s) in my reasoning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 1: I think it fails because you're using different partitions for your balls. First, you say you're partitioning your balls into the red (size: 5), white (size: 6) and blue (size: 7) balls, and using binomial coefficients to count the different possibilities for each set. But then you're partitioning the balls into the ones you've already chosen (size: 3) and the ones you haven't (size: 15). I think choosing different partitions is problematic in itself with these type of counting and multiplication calculations, and partitioning based on "having already chosen" balls also leads to problems.

For 2: note that not all 30-element vectors are valid outcomes. For example, if the first 20 elements are "r", then there is only one choice for the remaining 10 elements.

Comment: Now I see my mistakes. Thank you, Mark, very much. 1) I've found the way to count it right: there are six cases of how many balls of each color may be included into sample: for example, 3 red & 1 white & 1 blue, i.e.  (3,1,1) for short. It gives $\binom{5}{3}\binom{6}{1}\binom{7}{1}$ outcomes. And so on. Then, I added them, divided by total # of outcomes and got the correct answer.

Comment: Glad I could help!